# Matlab skipping subfolders

Tags: matlab, directory, skip

I have a folder containing sequential subfolders 000001_wd, 000002_wd,... in which I'm reading data contained in a file called 'plane.txt'.  Some of the subfolders don't contain that file.  I wish to skip them in a for-if else loop, but it is unable open file.

Tried changing or adding paths but nothing seems to work

```
workdir = 'D:\wass\test\output_925\';
cd(workdir)
data_frames = [1:1:37];

nframes = numel(data_frames);
V = zeros(nframes,3);
times = zeros(nframes,1);
ii=1;
prev = cd(workdir);
for frame = data_frames
    fprintf('Processing frame %d\n',frame);
    wdir = sprintf( '%s%06d_wd/', workdir, frame);
    cd(wdir)
     if exist('plane.txt')            
        plane_data = importdata([wdir,'plane.txt']);
        times(ii) = double(ii-1)/fps;
     else
        times(ii) = double(ii-1)/fps;
     end
    ii=ii+1;

end
cd(prev);

fprintf('Saving data...\n');
```

I want to just continue through the loop until the last subfolder.  Is there something I'm missing because the file I'm skipping is in a subfolder of my sequence?

Answer (score 1):

The statement `exist('plane.txt')` tests to see if the file 'plane.txt' exists in the current directory. If it does, you read a file in the `wdir` subdirectory. Obviously, you haven't tested if *that* file exists.

I would simplify your code by reading the data within a try/catch block:

```matlab
workdir = 'D:\wass\test\output_925\';
data_frames = 1:37; % <- don't use square brackets here, they're useless
nframes = numel(data_frames);
times = zeros(nframes,1);
for ii=1:nframes
    frame = data_frames(ii);
    fprintf('Processing frame %d\n',frame);
    wdir = sprintf( '%s%06d_wd/', workdir, frame);
    try
        plane_data = importdata([wdir,'plane.txt']);
        % do something with plane_data here...
    catch
        % ignore error
    end
    times(ii) = double(ii-1)/fps;
end
% ...
```

Note that I never used `cd`. You don't need to change directories to read data, and it's always better not to. The `importdata` statement uses an absolute path, so it does not matter what the current directory is.

---

A different approach involves getting a list of all files that match `'D:\wass\test\output_925\*\plane.txt'`:

```matlab
files = dir(fullfile(workdir, '*', 'plane.txt'));
for ii=1:numel(files)
   file = fullfile(files(ii).folder, files(ii).name);
   plane_data = importdata(file);
   % do something with plane_data here...
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much!, will try tomorrow, have to go to bed.  I just tried 
if ~contains('plane.txt', 'plane.txt')
instead of 
if exist('plane.txt')  

It seemed to work, but have to check the results.

Comment: @hclarke: That will always return `false`. You are comparing strings there, not looking on the file system.

Comment: OK, as I said, I have to sign off.  Thanks!